# When changing UIBarButtonItem title, the transition is jerky/flickers

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIViewController` subclass. I give the view controller a *rightBarButtonItem* in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Difficulty"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
      target:nil
      action:nil];
```

When the user presses another button in the view, the title/text of the `UIBarButtonItem` is changed like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Mellansvår";
```

It works fine, but when the title is changed, it doesn't look very good. The text jumps around a bit.

I have changed `UILabel` text at runtime before, and when I change their text is doesn't look like this, but I don't know how to add a `UILabel` to the *navigationItem*. I can't do it in Interface Builder because the navigation bar comes from a `UINavigationController`.

**Is there a way to change the title more smoothly?**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the title again, you could set the button again with the title and then animate it:

```
(void)setRightBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to change the title without animations.

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Mellansvår";
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the animation altogether, if you change the UIBarButtonItem title while it is **not attached to the navigationItem**, like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *tempItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
tempItem.title = @"Mellansvår";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = tempItem;
```

The animation will disappear completely, but the visual effect looks way better IMHO.