# UIBarButtonItem bad Edit/Done animation

Tags: ios, swift, edit, uibarbuttonitem

I've implemented an edit burron for my custom tableviewcontroller without using the default edit button. I have put a UIBarButton item in my storyboard and linked with IBOutlet in my custom class. I've implemented all these simple mechanisms for changing the button title:

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedMedicine: NSManagedObject?
var edit: Bool = false

@IBOutlet var editButton: UIBarButtonItem

@IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField
@IBOutlet var noteTextView: UITextView


@IBAction func enableEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !edit
    {
        println("editing")
        self.edit = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = "Done"
    }
    else
    {
        self.edit = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = "Edit"
    }
}
```

The title changes but there's something strange in the transition from Edit to Done because it's a little jerky.
I've found another one with my same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307907/when-changing-uibarbuttonitem-title-the-transition-is-jerky-flickers) but no one answered him.

You can look at this video for undertsand the bad animation i mean [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97698564/JerkyButtonChange.mov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually setting the bar button title and tracking state, you can use the built-in UIViewController.editButtonItem and UIViewController.editing property:

```
func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

@IBAction func enableEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.editing = !self.editing
}
```